# Convert MSAccess Project Management Application to PHP/MySQL: Which Methodology?

Tags: mysql, database, ms-access, methodology

I've got to convert a not terribly complicated bespoke project management system from MsAccess Application to PHP/MySQL. I've been programming for donkey's years but embarrassingly know practically nothing about modern methodologies.

So the old 'learning curve' versus 'improved efficiency' conundrum rears its ugly head once again.

Although I've Googled up some stuff I don't want to prejudice your suggestions, where would you start, I'm at your mercy?

What sort of learning curve am I looking at?

Comment: Having done a little research on this I can see the advantages of frameworks for new projects, but are as useful for creating a web application for an existing database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider learning a PHP framework and its philosophy and architecture to produce the application.  You'll be glad you did.

http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Basically, this will help you get up and running quickly with all of the necessary moving parts, in a way that promotes best practices.  IMO it's probably the quickest and best way to accomplish your goals.

For recommendations on which one to choose, have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184395/what-is-the-best-free-php-framework-working-on-shared-hosting-and-why

Comment: Robert, I'd already read that thread with some kind of tie between CakePHP and CodeIgniter but I don't know enough yet to made a choice

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows more about these frameworks than I do can help you make an informed choice. But using a framework of some kind is the way to go IMO. Both frameworks are probably pretty good. I personally would favor a framework that has an MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you say you been writing code for years, do you have any choice as to the final platform?

Access 2010 can create web based applications that scale horizontally in a HUGE way. The resulting applications don't requite Silverlight or even any ActiveX, but ONLY a standard browser. Here is a video of a application I wrote in Access, and note at the half way point I switch to running in a browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Access 2010 also now does have database triggers and stored procedures. However, you are hinting that you don't have a choice of technologies here so the above new features and even the new Web site creating ability of Access is thus moot for you.

I guess the 1st area I would start with is installing and setting up MySql. The MySql site has some good links to tutorials etc. You simply have to get up to speed with that database server and get conformable with it regardless of learning PHP anyway, so that one step and area I would start out with. And, if you worked with databases, then you find MySql quite easy to get up to speed with so you feel like you making some progress as you embark on this new road

Comment: Albert, I already know PHP/MySQL very well so that's my preference it's just a question whether I start hacking together some of my own scripts or I'm a good boy and finally start learning a methodology but which one?